# How to run selected Project in IntelliJ with maven?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea

in eclipse run configuration you can tell maven to run the project, which is selected with the variable `${selected_resource_loc}` in the run configuration.

How to do that in IntelliJ?

Comment: Would [Maven Helper plugin](http://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7179?pr=idea_ce) help?

Comment: Is it a lot of trouble to have the `Maven Projects` pane open on the right upper side of your screen, and run from there?

Comment: Where does that variable come from? You can create a maven run configuration either by selecting your maven goal on the right panel and selecting `Create {goal}` or by `Edit Run Configurations -> + -> Maven -> Select your module as working directory`